# jQuery input[type=number] decimals length @Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, number-formatting

I have written a dynamic form creation script in jQuery, problem are type=number fields.
The options to come with it are: step, min, max, default (=value) and decimals (var = dec).

Background: In my case the decimal length is sometimes not the same as the step attribute indices. So I wrote a script to force the length of the amount of numbers to fill up after the decimal, after proofing it is longer than the step (otherwise the input function is broken):

```js
//get decimal-setting and count digits of step inputs, to set appropriate decimals
jQuery('input[type="number"]').change(function () {
   dec = jQuery(this).attr("dec"); 
   step = jQuery(this).attr("step"); 
    decimals = (step.split('.')[1] || []).length;
    if (decimals > dec) dec = decimals;
    jQuery(this).val(function (i, text) {
     return (parseFloat(text)).toFixed(dec);
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="mynumber" name="mynumber" min="0.5" max="10" step="0.5" dec="5" value="1" />
```

This works fine, except in Firefox. Just Firefox ignores my change function and sets the decimals = step, which normally would be the right way.

How could I force FF to set decimals, too?